# HTTPS: Same certificate, different public key

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl, apache

I have a web server, Debian, and the site uses a HTTPS cert from Thawte. The root certificate meant to be on top of my verification chain is also on the server, in /etc/ssl/certs, because the APT packet ca-certificates in installed (the actual content of the certificate list Debian uses there apparently comes from Mozilla).

Now I checked the same root certificate from 4 different locations:
a) The file in /etc/ssl/certs, coming from packet ca-certificates
b) The file contained in a fresh download of said APT packet, on a WIndows PC, just to look at the files
c) The root certificate downloaded from Thawtes website itself
d) The root certificate as used by my browser, Firefox, on Windows.

The problem is, only the debian-related ones (a and b) are the same, ie. I have three different certificates there. Name, fingerprint etc. are always the same, but the public key and some other values are completely different.

My question: Is this normal? Or do I have a huge reason to worry now?

I noticed that because I can't verify my site certificate on the server (SSH, with OpenSSL in the command line); OpenSSL isn't satisfied with the local CA files.

Comment: Since the public key is part of the certificate and the fingerprint is a hash of the full certificate it is impossible that the fingerprint is the same while the public key is different.

Comment: My first guess would be that the values are shown in different formats.

Comment: Do you use the same software to view certificates? Did you try to check them on the same machine (like, $ openssl x509 -fingerprint -pubkey -noout -in <cert_file>)?

Comment: @Somebody0987: Could you post the certificates here or on a pastebin site?

Comment: Sorry, everyone, as said by SteffenUllrich this whole thing is impossible = nonsense. I'm certain now that there is no breach of my server or anything. The 3 causes were a) being a little bit braindead after searching the problem for 6h (and the actual situation involves PHP and Plesk too; a PHP upgrade triggered the problem in the first place because now file_get_content insists on correct certificates even locally) ...(continue  below)

Comment: and, more importantly, b) Thawte has a really whacky system of ~10 cross-root-certificates being connected somewhat randomly, and c) the OpenSSL version in Debian stable is a little bit too old to understand Thawte (Bug already known). Solution for the commandline was to install OpenSSL from Debian testing. PHP will be upgraded shortly, and then it should be ok again.